# cannot find output "eDP-1"

Tags: nvidia

I have a MSI laptop with a NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX1060 Graphic Card and UBUNTU 18.04.

I haven't been able to work on 2 Displays (the second one a HDMI). The NVIDIA drivers seemed to not be working even though I installed and update the drivers...
Finally I founf that SECURE BOOT must be disabled to make the NVIDIA drivers works. I worked actually. I could make my HDMI port work but sadly my laptop edp-1 screen stop working.

I really need help with this. I have tried too many things but it haven't worked.

Comment: What were you doing, where do you get that output ? Is it from `xrandr` ?

Comment: Yes. I couldn't post that on the tittle. It said already existed.
But you're right is on the Xrandr... I can now only use one or the other...
Laptop Screen or External, each case, I have to change the Secure Boot config

Comment: [Edit] your post, please paste the output.

Comment: OK...
Do you know what can be happening with this xrandr: cannot find output edp-1

Comment: I'm sorry what I mean is what command you ran that produce the error ?

Comment: It actually is not an error when I installed all the drivers...
The thigns is, for some reason UBUNTU doesn't get the NVIDIA drivers to be the primary when SECURE BOOT is enabled.

I found that changing it to DISABLED will change the driver from INTEL to NVIDIA and it worked, it let the HDMI monitor work, but then the laptop screen, the eDP-1 just didn't work anymore...

I have to reset the SECURE BOOT to ENABLE.

Comment: I did disabled SECURE BOOT